# std::tuple_cat substitution failure

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples

I use `std::tuple_cat` to do subset selections of argument lists into tuples, like so:

```
template <class...>
struct odds;

template <class T1>
struct odds<T1>
{
    typedef std::tuple<T1> type;
    static type value(T1&& t1)
    {
        return std::make_tuple(std::forward<T1>(t1));
    }
};

template <class T1, class T2>
struct odds<T1, T2>
{
    typedef std::tuple<T1> type;
    static type value(T1&& t1, T2&&)
    {
        return std::make_tuple(std::forward<T1>(t1));
    }
};

template <class T1, class T2, class... TTail> 
struct odds<T1, T2, TTail...>
{
        typedef decltype(std::tuple_cat(T1(), typename odds<TTail...>::type())) type; // L32
        static type value(T1&& t1, T2&&, TTail&&... rest)
    {
        return std::tuple_cat(std::forward<T1>(t1), odds<TTail...>::value(std::forward<TTail>(rest)...)); // L35
    }
};
```

, with the following as a test case:

```
// assume <tuple>, <utility> are included at top of file
template <class... T>
auto foo(T... x) -> typename odds<T...>::type
{
         return odds<T...>::value(x...);
         //...
 }       
 int main() {
         auto bar = foo(5, true, 6, false); // L46
         auto baz = odds<int, bool, int, bool>::value(5, true, 6, false); // L47
         // bar, baz should be tuple<int,int> with value { 5, 6 }
 }
```

However, template deduction issues arise in both clang-3.1 and gcc-4.7.2:

Clang output:

```
test.cc:32:19: error: no matching function for call to 'tuple_cat'
        typedef decltype(std::tuple_cat(T1(), typename odds<TTail...>::type())) type;
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test.cc:40:30: note: in instantiation of template class 'odds<int, bool, int, bool>' requested here
auto foo(T... x) -> typename odds<T...>::type
                             ^
test.cc:40:6: note: while substituting deduced template arguments into function template 'foo' [with T = <int, bool, int, bool>]
auto foo(T... x) -> typename odds<T...>::type
     ^
/usr/include/c++/v1/tuple:1063:1: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with _Tuple0 = int, _Tuples = <std::__1::tuple<int>>]
tuple_cat(_Tuple0&& __t0, _Tuples&&... __tpls)
^
/usr/include/c++/v1/tuple:987:1: note: candidate function not viable: requires 0 arguments, but 2 were provided
tuple_cat()
^
test.cc:46:13: error: no matching function for call to 'foo'
        auto bar = foo(5, true, 6, false);
                   ^~~
test.cc:40:6: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with T = <int, bool, int, bool>]
auto foo(T... x) -> typename odds<T...>::type
     ^
test.cc:35:10: error: no matching function for call to 'tuple_cat'
                return std::tuple_cat(std::forward<T1>(t1), odds<TTail...>::value(std::forward<TTail>(rest)...));
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test.cc:47:41: note: in instantiation of member function 'odds<int, bool, int, bool>::value' requested here
        auto baz = odds<int, bool, int, bool>::value(5,true,6,false);
                                               ^
/usr/include/c++/v1/tuple:1063:1: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with _Tuple0 = int, _Tuples = <std::__1::tuple<int>>]
tuple_cat(_Tuple0&& __t0, _Tuples&&... __tpls)
^
/usr/include/c++/v1/tuple:987:1: note: candidate function not viable: requires 0 arguments, but 2 were provided
tuple_cat()
^
3 errors generated.
```

Gcc output:

```
test.cc: In instantiation of ‘struct odds<int, bool, int, bool>’:
test.cc:40:6:   required by substitution of ‘template<class ... T> typename odds<T ...>::type foo(T ...) [with T = {int, bool, int, bool}]’
test.cc:46:34:   required from here
test.cc:32:74: error: no matching function for call to ‘tuple_cat(int, odds<int, bool>::type)’
test.cc:32:74: note: candidate is:
In file included from test.cc:1:0:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/include/g++-v4/tuple:1027:5: note: template<class ... _Tpls, class> constexpr typename std::__tuple_cat_result<_Tpls ...>::__type std::tuple_cat(_Tpls&& ...)
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/include/g++-v4/tuple:1027:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/include/g++-v4/tuple:1024:31: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct std::enable_if<false, void>’
test.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cc:46:34: error: no matching function for call to ‘foo(int, bool, int, bool)’
test.cc:46:34: note: candidate is:
test.cc:40:6: note: template<class ... T> typename odds<T ...>::type foo(T ...)
test.cc:40:6: note:   substitution of deduced template arguments resulted in errors seen above
test.cc:46:34: error: unable to deduce ‘auto’ from ‘<expression error>’
test.cc:47:13: error: ‘value’ is not a member of ‘odds<int, bool, int, bool>’
test.cc:47:61: error: unable to deduce ‘auto’ from ‘<expression error>’
```

Gcc is a bit more helpful here, especially with the error

```
    test.cc:32:74: error: no matching function for call to ‘tuple_cat(int, odds<int, bool>::type)’
```

The goal is to call a function which recursively unpacks arguments, collects the selections into a collecting tuple, and returns it. To accumulate it in a flat manner, I'm using `std::tuple_cat()` to flatten the recursive tail tuple, add a head, and return the tuple. Forwarding is used in order to not drop reference qualifiers during recursion.

Later on in the code, the resulting tuple is unpacked to call a different variadic function, but that's outside the scope of this error.

Clearly, I've omitted some subtle yet crucial detail somewhere, but I am finding significant difficulty in tracking down the underlying issue.

Comment: Please provide a complete example that can actually be compiled to reproduce your error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arguments to `tuple_cat` must be tuples (or "tuple-like" things which support the `std::tuple_size` and `std::tuple_element` API, such as `std::pair` or `std::array`) but from the error message you seem to be calling it with non-tuple types.  To do that you'd probably want something like:

```
std::tuple_cat(std::make_tuple(a_non_tuple), a_tuple, another_tuple);
```

This turns the first argument into a `tuple<decltype(a_non_tuple)>` so it can be concatenated with the other tuples.

> to concatenate `std::tuple<T1, std::tuple<T2, std::tuple<T3, ...>>>` into `std::tuple<T1, T2, T3, ...>`

That's not "concatenation".  I think the correct term for that is "flattening".

I'm not really sure what you're trying, because you haven't provided a complete example.  Are you calling `foo` with an argument like `std::tuple<T1, std::tuple<T2, std::tuple<T3, ...>>>`?

That won't work, because `foo` will deduce `T` as `std::tuple<T1, std::tuple<T2, std::tuple<T3, ...>>>` and instantiate the `odds<T1>` specialization, which just wraps the argument to `foo` inside *another* tuple!

Comment: Bingo. I missed the quasi-tupleness in the variadic example in http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple_cat . Replacing `T1()` in the `decltype` with `typename std::tuple<T1>()` and wrapping the forwarded `t1` inside `std::make_tuple()` fixed it.

Comment: Emphasize "must be tuples" and the "non" in the last paragraph for accept and upvote.

Comment: Sheesh, I guessed what was wrong without seeing all the code and solved the problem, isn't that enough for an upvote?! You're hard to please ;)  I've rearranged the answer to put the relevant paragraph first.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is interesting to you, since it is an alternative implementation, rather than an answer to your question. I think using `tuple_cat` like that is going to end up doing a lot of moves/copies at runtime, although perhaps a compiler can avoid these for trivial types. Anyway, it seemed like an interesting TMP problem.

This is what I came up with (which is quite possibly overly verbose); it could definitely use some clean-up (and the clang version I have -- trunk as of a few weeks ago -- asserts while trying to compile it).

The interesting recursive bit is in `Skip`, where it uses the previous tuple as a pattern (count, really) to construct the next one; you can see how, in the end, Odds passes the two-argument pattern, using SkipHelper, to set up the initial call. (That part could definitely use some work, and maybe it would have been easier to use a number):

```
namespace skip_args {
namespace detail {

// We use Tuple as a kind of generic typelist.
template<typename ...T>
using Tuple = std::tuple<T...>;

// Utility "functions"
// Pusher<T, Tuple<U...> >::type = Tuple<T, U...>
template<typename A, typename B> struct Pusher;
template<typename T, typename ...U> struct Pusher<T, Tuple<U...>> {
  using type = Tuple<T, U...>;
};
template<typename A, typename B>
using push = typename Pusher<A, B>::type;

// Skip is an intermediate used to skip over ignored elements.
// To allow recursion, we declare the general form first.
// All three arguments are Tuples.
template<typename Next, typename Rest, typename This> struct Skip;

// Node is actually used to store some data item. It also inherits from the next
// following Node (if there is one) so that we end up with an inheritance chain.
// (That's the part similar to libstdc++ tuples; it makes the layout the same,
// too, as long as there's no EBO to deal with, because we don't bother here.)
template<typename Rest, typename ...This> struct Node;

template<typename ...R_, typename T, typename ...T_>
struct Node<Tuple<R_...>, T, T_...>
: Skip<Tuple<>, Tuple<R_...>, Tuple<T, T_...>>::type {
  using self = Node<Tuple<R_...>, T, T_...>;
  using next = typename Skip<Tuple<>, Tuple<R_...>, Tuple<T, T_...>>::type;
  // Recursive construction of node types
  using nodes = push<self, typename next::nodes>;
  using value_type = T;
  // The constructor takes all the arguments, uses the first one, skips some,
  // and passes the rest to the next node.
  constexpr Node<Tuple<R_...>, T, T_...>(T&& t, T_&&...t_, R_&&...r_)
      : next(std::forward<R_>(r_)...), value(std::forward<T>(t)) {
  }
  T&& value;
};

// Base:
template<>
struct Node<Tuple<>> {
  using nodes = Tuple<>;
  constexpr Node<Tuple<>>() {}
};

// Skip (N...) (R R...) (T T...) => Skip (N... R) (R...) (T...)
// In other words, it drops elements from the third tuple, and for each one it
// moves an element from the second tuple to the first tuple. If it runs out of
// the third tuple, it "returns" a new Node. If it runs out of the second tuple,
// then we're done, but to satisfy the node requirements, it actually needs to
// declare a constructor (which drops all its arguments)

// General case:
template<typename ...N_, typename R, typename ...R_, typename T, typename ...T_>
struct Skip<Tuple<N_...>, Tuple<R, R_...>, Tuple<T, T_...>>
  : Skip<Tuple<N_..., R>, Tuple<R_...>, Tuple<T_...>> {
};
// Ran out of pattern
template<typename ...N_, typename R_, typename T_>
struct Skip<Tuple<N_...>, R_, T_> {
  using type = Node<R_, N_...>;
  using nodes = typename type::nodes;
};

template<typename T> struct TupleTyper;
template<typename ...T> struct TupleTyper<Tuple<T...>> {
  using type = Tuple<typename T::value_type...>;
};

template<typename A, typename B, typename C> struct TupleMaker;
template<typename Tup, typename H, typename ...T>
struct TupleMaker<Tup, H, Tuple<T...>> {
  Tup operator()(H&& helper) {
    return Tup(static_cast<T&>(helper).value...);
  }
};

template<typename N> struct SkipHelper {
  using tuple_type = typename TupleTyper<typename N::nodes>::type;
  template<typename ...U>
  tuple_type operator()(U&& ...u) {
    return TupleMaker<tuple_type, N, typename N::nodes>()(N(std::forward<U>(u)...));
  }
};

} // namespace detail

template<typename ...T> struct Odds;

template<typename T1, typename T2, typename ...T_>
struct Odds<T1, T2, T_...>
  : detail::SkipHelper<detail::Node<detail::Tuple<T_...>, T1, T2>> {
};
template<typename T1>
struct Odds<T1> : detail::SkipHelper<detail::Node<detail::Tuple<>, T1>> {
};

// tuple_from_odds takes any number of arguments,
// and returns a tuple of the odd numbered ones.
template<typename...T> auto tuple_from_odds(T&&...t)
    -> typename Odds<T...>::tuple_type {
  return Odds<T...>()(std::forward<T>(t)...);
}

} // namespace skip_args
```

Comment: @moshbear: I kinda figured out why clang crashed; it's because I was using std::tuple as a kind of type list. There's something about the libstdc++ implementation of std::tuple which disagrees with clang. Anyway, I changed `using Tuple=std::tuple;` to a simple type list structure (` template<typename...T> struct Tuple<T...> {};` and then only used `std::tuple` where I needed a `std::tuple`. That made clang happy again, and I remembered why I always use my own TypeList structs when I need a list of types for TMP.